# show 0 in a log scale y axis of plot in R

Tags: r

Because the y values are too small, I need to use a log scale for y axis to show the differences.
In the data, some entries do not have any value (0). Is there any way to show '0' at the y axis?

```
y=c(0.1, 0.001, 0.00001, 0.0000001, 0.000000001, 0)
x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
plot(x, y, log="y");
```

Thanks

Comment: As I guess you're aware, log(0) is -infinity.  Where would you like 0 items to be drawn?

Comment: I think what he want is to have 0 (zero) at the y axis

Answer (score 3):

I found myself doing something similar although also completely different. For people who has stumbled here what I did might be of some use perhaps.

I had the problem that I had very large numbers that I wanted to show on a logarithmic scale but also some zeros. I went with a barplot and used NA for the 0s. It turns out that NA is left as empty space which I think makes sense in this case. I made an example of only 10 numbers but R seems to handle scaling for more values quite good:

```
values<-c(100000, 100, 2, 5, NA, NA, 2, 1, NA, 1)
barplot(values, names=1:length(values), log="y")
```

[image: illustrative image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is 0 (zero) just to show on the y axis

How about this

```
y=c(0.1, 0.001, 0.00001, 0.0000001, 0.000000001, 0.0000000001)
x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
plot(x, y, log="y",yaxt="n")
axis(2,at=c(0.1, 0.001, 0.00001, 0.0000001, 0.000000001, 0.0000000001) ,labels=c(0.1, 0.001, 0.00001, 0.0000001, 0.000000001,"0"))
```

[image]

in `plot` `yaxt="n"` disables the drawing of the yaxis
then i manually draw a y axis with `axis` and set the `ticks` location with the `at` argument. Then I set the lowest value i have (in your case 0.0000000001) to the **character** `"0"` (at the `label` argument)

Comment: No. On a log-scale, 0 would show up way, way down there... It's like asking to see -infinity on a linear-scale graph.

Comment: I know and you are correct, but it would not make any sense to plot something like that. This is just what I can think about for getting the label `0` in the y axis.

Comment: IMHO, it's your resulting `y` axis that make no sense. Maybe the solution is to have two graphs on top of each other. The one below will just be for `y == 0`. Both graphs will share the same `x` axis but have their own separate `y` axis.

Comment: It is the closet answer to what I want to know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Choose some minimum value, and use that to represent 0:

```
m <- min(y[y!=0])/10
plot(x, pmax(y, m), log="y")
```

[image]

Comment: But you'll get a much different graph if you use 1e-100. I think the OP has some thinking to do like @Oli pointed out.