# R: Using logarithmic and linear axis scale on one axis

Tags: r, logarithm

I hit a dead end, finding a solution to my problem:

I want to draw a graph with the y axis being scaled logarithmically. The only problem is, I have one value that is 0. My solution to the problem of not log10(0) not being defined would be to break the y axis into one part that is scaled linear, from, say 0 to 0.001 and a second part that is logarithmic with the following values 0.00001, 0.000001, and 0.000001.

I have searched for almost a day now and couldn't find a Way to do this. Is there a parameter to break.axis or something similar I have missed?

What I have so far is pretty simple stuff:

```
d <- read.csv2(file="Verdunstungfuergrafik.csv")
plot(d, type="b", xaxt="n", yaxt="n", xlab="ABA-Konzentration in mol/l",     ylab="Verdunstung in g/gFw", col="blue1")
sfsmisc::eaxis(side=1, at=10^c(-6:-4))
sfsmisc::eaxis(side=2)
```

The imported CSV file looks like this:

```
Abakonzentration Verdunstung
0e+00      0.5770
1e-06      0.3600
1e-05      0.0800
1e-04      0.0685
```

Comment: There's a problem with your idea--if you take a log of .01 it's going to be negative, i.e. below the points to the left

Comment: i.e., the transformation you have in mind is discontinuous, and worse, it's not 1-1 or monotone: [here](http://www4f.wolframalpha.com/Calculate/MSP/MSP57321ed3gei368gfhf2i0000384he1iebfid52e0?MSPStoreType=image/gif&s=1&w=359.&h=152.&cdf=RangeControl)

Comment: Perhaps you can try the transformation `function(y)if (y<.001) y else log(y)-log(.001)+.001`, which is continuous; then manually set the `y` ticks using `axis` to be part-linear-part-log

Comment: Thank your for your answer! But that would transform the data itself, wouldnt it? I just want to transform, how it is displayed on the y axis. What is so bad about it being dicontinuous? Thats what the break accompanied by a break sign is for...

Comment: any representation that's not the identity (including log axes) will inherently "transform" the data. you don't have to _overwrite_ your original data, however

Comment: theres nothing necessarily wrong with a discontinuous transformation, per se. but your particular transformation is not monotone. for example, .001 will be represented as .001 on your chart. but .002 will be represented as log(.002)~=-3. this means that data near .001 will appear above data near .002, even though clearly the latter should be above the former.

Comment: Ah, ok. Of course your right. Well, I'll go with your solution then. Thank you very much. Although i still think it is odd you cant break an axis into a linear and a logarithmic block seperated by a break sign. As far as i now, in Origin Lab thats possible. Ive never personally tried it though.

Comment: can't say I'm familiar within origin block, but I'm sure underneath the hood it's doing something similar

Comment: check out these similar questions for some more pointers: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309336/show-0-in-a-log-scale-y-axis-of-plot-in-r), [2](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58126/plotting-0-in-a-log-scaled-axis), and especially [3](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try `magaxis()` in `magicaxis` R package.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Since I am new to R I still find it hard to conclude what to do simply from the package manual. Could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks in advance.