# Limit the height of bar chart in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have data divided in almost 25 categories. Almost all of the categories have 1000 or less products in each except for 2 or 3 categories which have more than 3000 or 4000 products. So when i plot the `barchartGC` of products vs categories because of these 2/3 categories rest of the bars looks very small.

I was wondering if there is any way in which we divide the height of our bar charts in 2 or 3 levels. First level for less than 1000 products and second level for those more than that products.

[image]

Comment: Is logarithmic scaling an option? For example as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309336/show-0-in-a-log-scale-y-axis-of-plot-in-r/14522440#14522440

Comment: Log scaling won't really show the difference in number of products between two categories. If some category has 10 times more products it will be shown as double.

Comment: You may also try `facet` by spiting data based on the levels required

Comment: you can try package `plotrix`, function `axis.break`. A reproducible example would make it easier to help you. See [ask]

Comment: This is probably the only way of presenting the data when you want to compare different products. Huge gap between product frequencies? Good.